# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException para gravar no banco de dados MySQL

Tags: java

Boa noite pessoal!

Estou com um problema de gravar o log de atividades do meu sistema, a situação é a seguinte o sistema é um chat socket multi usuário na minha classe que contém a interface gráfica está o código que captura os dados de acesso.

Logo abaixo é a minha classe LogModel

```
private int LOG_CODIGO;
private String LOG_USUARIO;
private String LOG_STATUS;
private String LOG_DATA;
private String LOG_HORA;
private String LOG_IPV4;
private String LOG_HOSTNAME;

public LogModel() {

}

public LogModel(int LOG_CODIGO, String LOG_USUARIO, String LOG_STATUS, String LOG_DATA, String LOG_HORA, String LOG_IPV4, String LOG_HOSTNAME) {
    this.LOG_CODIGO = LOG_CODIGO;
    this.LOG_USUARIO = LOG_USUARIO;
    this.LOG_STATUS = LOG_STATUS;
    this.LOG_DATA = LOG_DATA;
    this.LOG_HORA = LOG_HORA;
    this.LOG_IPV4 = LOG_IPV4;
    this.LOG_HOSTNAME = LOG_HOSTNAME;
}

public int getLOG_CODIGO() {
    return LOG_CODIGO;
}

public void setLOG_CODIGO(int LOG_CODIGO) {
    this.LOG_CODIGO = LOG_CODIGO;
}

public String getLOG_USUARIO() {
    return LOG_USUARIO;
}

public void setLOG_USUARIO(String LOG_USUARIO) {
    this.LOG_USUARIO = LOG_USUARIO;
}

public String getLOG_STATUS() {
    return LOG_STATUS;
}

public void setLOG_STATUS(String LOG_STATUS) {
    this.LOG_STATUS = LOG_STATUS;
}

public String getLOG_DATA() {
    return LOG_DATA;
}

public void setLOG_DATA(String LOG_DATA) {
    this.LOG_DATA = LOG_DATA;
}

public String getLOG_HORA() {
    return LOG_HORA;
}

public void setLOG_HORA(String LOG_HORA) {
    this.LOG_HORA = LOG_HORA;
}

public String getLOG_IPV4() {
    return LOG_IPV4;
}

public void setLOG_IPV4(String LOG_IPV4) {
    this.LOG_IPV4 = LOG_IPV4;
}

public String getLOG_HOSTNAME() {
    return LOG_HOSTNAME;
}

public void setLOG_HOSTNAME(String LOG_HOSTNAME) {
    this.LOG_HOSTNAME = LOG_HOSTNAME;
}
```

}

A classe abaixo é a minha classe LogDao

public class LogDao {

```
private final Connection conexao;

public LogDao() {

    this.conexao = Conexao.getConexao();

}

public void adicionar(LogModel logmodel) throws SQLException {

    String SQL = "INSERT INTO LOG_ACESSO (LOG_USUARIO, LOG_STATUS, LOG_DATA, LOG_HORA, LOG_IPV4, LOG_HOSTNAME) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    PreparedStatement stmt = conexao.prepareStatement(SQL);
    stmt.setString(1, logmodel.getLOG_USUARIO());
    stmt.setString(2, logmodel.getLOG_STATUS());
    stmt.setString(3, logmodel.getLOG_DATA());
    stmt.setString(4, logmodel.getLOG_HORA());
    stmt.setString(5, logmodel.getLOG_IPV4());
    stmt.setString(6, logmodel.getLOG_HOSTNAME());

    stmt.executeUpdate();
    stmt.close();
}
```

}

A classe a baixo é a minha classe de conexão

public class Conexao {

```
private final static String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private final static String BANCO = "jdbc:mysql://10.10.10.7/CHAT";
private final static String USUARIO = "carpezani";
private final static String SENHA = "1q2w3e4r5t";

private static Connection conexao;

public Conexao() {
    try {

        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(BANCO, USUARIO, SENHA);

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro na classe de conexão do banco. \n" + ex.getMessage());
        conexao = null;

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro ao conectar no banco.\n" + ex.getMessage());
        conexao = null;
    }
}

public static Connection getConexao() {

    return conexao;
}

public static void fecharConexao() {
    try {

        conexao.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {

        System.out.println("Falha ao fechar conexao.\n" + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

E o evento do botão conectar que captura as informações e joga pro banco de dados.

private void btnCONECTARActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    String nome = this.edtCONEXAO.getText(); // variavel recebendo infomação do usuario

    // validação de conexão
    if (nome.isEmpty()) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Por favor, informe o usuário!", "Mensagem",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

    } else {

        this.menssagem = new ChatMenssagem(); // inicilização do ChatMenssagem
        this.menssagem.setAction(Action.CONECTADO); // faz a requisição de conexão.
        this.menssagem.setNome(nome); // nome do usuario que foi digitado na interface

        this.service = new ChatService(); // inicializar a classe ChatService
        this.socket = this.service.conexao(); // retornando um socket

        new Thread(new ListenerSocket(this.socket)).start();  // objeto socket é passado para a Thread

        this.service.Send(menssagem); // retorno da mensagem
    }

    try {

        LogModel logmodel = new LogModel();

        logmodel.setLOG_CODIGO(Integer.parseInt(lblCODIGO.getText()));
        logmodel.setLOG_USUARIO(edtCONEXAO.getText());
        logmodel.setLOG_STATUS(edtCONEXAO.getText());
        logmodel.setLOG_DATA(lblDATA.getText());
        logmodel.setLOG_HORA(lblHORA.getText());
        logmodel.setLOG_IPV4(lblIPV4.getText());
        logmodel.setLOG_HOSTNAME(lblHOSTNAME.getText());

        LogDao dao = new LogDao();
        dao.adicionar(logmodel);

    } catch (SQLException erro) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Erro:" + erro.getMessage(), "Erro",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

}
```

E finalmente o erro que está aparecendo no console.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.aps.app.dao.LogDao.adicionar(LogDao.java:23)
    at com.aps.app.frame.ChatJanela.btnCONECTARActionPerformed(ChatJanela.java:430)
    at com.aps.app.frame.ChatJanela.access$500(ChatJanela.java:33)
    at com.aps.app.frame.ChatJanela$1.actionPerformed(ChatJanela.java:244)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(AWTEventMulticaster.java:289)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6539)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Pessoal se alguém conseguir me ajudar eu agradeço desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente sua conexão está nula quando você chama atravez do Conexao.getConexao(), como ele é um método estático ele não passo pelo construtor que é onde você crio a conexão, sugiro da um olha no pattern singleton para o que você está tentando fazer

Comment: Eu acabei debugando e acabei visualizando que a conexão estava nula mesmo, será que se eu tirar o static do método resolveria?

Comment: sim, nesse caso sim

Comment: Eu retirei, mas ele reclamou na classe LogDao nesse trecho

Comment: public LogDao() {
        
        this.conexao = Conexao.getConexao();
        
    }

Comment: nesse caso é que já que ele deixou de ser static você tem que instanciar a classe conexao

Comment: A beleza vou tentar aqui

Comment: Velho deu certo, muito obrigado mesmo sério!

Comment: Basicamente você é um Deus do java kkkk valeu irmão.

Comment: Opa que isso man sou mero aprendiz ainda, tenta da um olha no pattern singleton para usar na sua classe conexão